# How to kill all mobs of a certain type in a radius and summon a new named mob?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

For my server I want to have special items, and I've already looked up all the commands for the entities to work but I found a flaw with one - all entities within the radius change. Is it possible to kill all entities within a radius (shot by a specific named item) and /summon a named mob in its place? Basically:

- Shoot bow/snowball
- Kill shot arrow/snowball from named bow/snowball within a radius of 1 for all players (with /execute)
- Summon a named arrow/snowball

How would I do this?

Comment: This would probably requir thousands of command blocks

Comment: Oh, I forgot. I'm in 1.11.2 Bukkit and the bow has to be enchanted. @ExperimentalRocket I doubt it. All it has to do is kill an arrow shot from a special bow, and summon a named arrow. I already have all the commands for the lightning arrow - I just don't want all arrows to be lightning arrows.

Comment: But the arrow will look weird and will fly in the wrong direction.

Comment: You just want to summon it and it to stay there?

Comment: No. I want to summon it and have it go in the same direction as the original arrow.

Comment: Thousands of command blocks

Comment: I made an answer for some of the commands that you need but you need to make your question more specific. That does summon an arrow but it wont move.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so this is for summoning an *immobile* arrow:

Add a repeating command block (always active) with the following command:

```
/execute @e[type=Arrow] ~ ~ ~ /summon Arrow ~ ~ ~ {CustomName:NAMEHERE}
```

Add a chain command block to the back of the repeating command blockthats always active and conditional

```
/execute @a ~ ~ ~ /kill @e[type=Arrow,r=4]
```

Your question is unclear

The arrow will not move. It would require hundreds, at the very least, of command blocks. Nevertheless, I wish you luck. I could try to improve it if I could get on your server but I will not be able to
 make it perfect.

Comment: Alright. Thanks for trying to help, the IP is cursedskies.aternos.me, I'll most likely have the commands in the server spawn chunks and the acidisland world spawn chunks. Side question: Is there any way I can have commands loaded in two different worlds?

Comment: Do you have plugins?

Comment: Yes, I do. I have multiple.

Comment: Is there no plugin out there for what you want to do?

Comment: I'm not sure if there is a plugin that can do that. I don't know what to search for because Aternos doesn't have FTP.

Comment: Aha... Well i will try to help you. The IP is not working is the server offline?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/52983/discussion-between-finn-and-experimental-rocket).